# Send GraphQLUpload to imagekit.io from node server running express-graphql

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, express-graphql, imagekit

Inexperienced dev here. This issue is driving me crazy.

I am sending an image file from a react front end via a graphQL mutation to a node server running express-graphql.
The uploadFile mutation works correctly, and I am able to save the file locally on the server.

I want to upload this file to imagekit.io, return the url, and then send the url to the client as the return of the graqhQL mutation.I am using the imagekit npm package, and I have configured it as described in the api docs.

Ultimately I'd rather stream the file straight to imagekit without saving it to the server, but I'm still researching whether this is possible (advice appreciated), but that's not the main issue.

The image is sent via imagekit.upload() to imagekit, and the return message states that it is saved successfully, however the file-type is 'non-image' regardless of the file type (tried jpg, png, webp).

The image saved locally to the node server is (as far as I can tell) identical to the image sent from the client. The image is also visible in my imagekit media library, but the filesize is incorrect (< 100 bytes). These two observations together lead me to believe that the wrong string is being sent to imagekit, but I have no idea how to encode it properly.

Any pointers/help anyone can give would be really appreciated.

**app.js (server)**

```
import schema from './schema'
...
app.use('/graphql', 
    graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }),
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema,
        graphiql: true
    })
)
...
```

**schema.js**

```
import {GraphQLUpload} from 'graphql-upload'
...
const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        uploadFile:{
            description: 'Uploads a file',
            type: GraphQLString,
            args: {
                file: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLUpload)},
            },
            async resolve(parent, {file}){
                const { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = await file

            await new Promise(res => 
                createReadStream()
                  .pipe(createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, "./", filename), {encoding:'base64'}))
                  .on("close", res)

              ).then (                 
                    imagekit.upload({
                        file : path.join(__dirname, "./", filename), //required
                        fileName : filename,   //required

                        }, function(error, result) {

                            if(error) 
                                console.log(error)
                            else {
                                filesArray.push(filename)
                                console.log(result)
                            } 
                        }
                    )  
                )
                return 'Promise that returns the url'
            }
        },
```

Response from imagekit.upload():

```
{
  filePath: '/default-image_ANV6NYo5o.jpg',
  size: 36,
  fileId: '5db1ccc9e954fe57f4c791c9',
  url: 'https://ik.imagekit.io/<My imagekit ID here>/default-image_ANV6NYo5o.jpg',
  name: 'default-image_ANV6NYo5o.jpg',
  fileType: 'non-image'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue after researching proper use of fs.createReadStream and Promises.
Encoding and sending just the stream works perfectly.

```
async function encodeFile(file) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        let { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = file

        let encodedFile
        createReadStream()
        .on('data', chunk => {
            encodedFile = chunk.toString('base64')
        })
        .on('close', () => {
            resolve(uploadFile(filename, encodedFile))
        })

    });
  }
```